# How to send parameter with API in get method

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, laravel-api

I have to run an API on postmen, the project is based upon Laravel. The endpoint is mention below

```
`Route::get('order/detail/{order}', 'OrdersController@show');`
```

here is my order controller function:

```
public function show(Order $order)  
{   
    dd("ok");
}
```

I am trying to run API using postmen and receiving 404 error
[image]

but when I removed {order} from endpoints, it worked. so my question is how can I run this API on postmen. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Route::get('order/detail/{order}', 'OrdersController@show');`

You must use the endpoint is `http://localhost:8082/v3/order/detail/45487`.

Not `...order/detail?order=45487`

then

```
public function show($order)  //$order is 45487
{   
    dd("ok");
}
```